# modify the default tab display structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working on angularJS. I have created tabs using angularJS, want to modify the way the tabs looks.

I wanted to display the tabs with rounded corners as shown in the image below. 
[image]

I was having tough time to achieve this using css.
Please suggest how can i get the rounded corners of the tabs as shown in the above image.
Please find my working code here http://plnkr.co/edit/niK4d4YEdkSkZy2UZiHX?p=preview

CSS Code:

```
  <style>
    .nav-tabs>li>a, .nav-tabs>li>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li>a:focus {
     background-color: #D0D0D0;
     }
   </style>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsParentController">
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
         heading="{{workspace.name}}"
         active=workspace.active>
        <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
            --some dynamic content here--
        </div>
     </tab>
</tabset>
```

Please suggest the best possible way to achieve the rounded corners for the tabs displayed. I can use CSS or bootstrap to achieve this.